# PWA app offline cache clearing issue on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, angularjs, safari, progressive-web-apps

We have developed a PWA angular application and used index db to store the offline data. Everything work fine including offline website functionalities using index DB data. For the reserach purpose, we have loaded our PWA app to iPad safari browser and then we didnt perform any functonalities for a day.

After a day we tried to load the app in the offline mode , we couldnt see the website functioning in the offline mode. It shows "safari cannot open the page. because your ipad is connected to the internet. message in the browser

We used WorkBox and used "staleWhileRevalidate" strategy.

Do any body know why the cache storage expires after one day in safari browser? We can see cache is persisting on the PC and Android browsers?

Please give your suggestion to keep the cache in the safari browser on ipad and MAC devices?

We also notified that none of the ipad browsers keeping the cache more than one day.

Our latest research identifies that restarting the ios device causing automatic clearing of cache. When restarting the ios device, we could see the website data for all the website on the safari browsers are automatically clearing. How can we persist it for a website?

Comment: so let me get this right - you are depending on browser cache to sync back to the server?

Comment: Yes. I am planning so

Comment: info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage#Browser_compatibility

Comment: To help with debugging, you could also plug your iPad and open Safari with remote debugging and in the console inspect your `window.caches` (even though they were cached from the service worker scope). Can you confirm that window.caches is empty after you restart the device?

Comment: did you publish to app store OR are you using add to home screen? If you are able to publish to app store .. please let me know how . .